# Need map function to run another function only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm running a map function in which I want it to return a function if a condition is met, otherwise, run another function.

The issue though is that when the condition is not met, the function is running as many times as the condition is false. I just want the second function to run only once.

So here's my code:

```
  handleVote(name, url) {
    this.props.bandsVoted.map(band => {
      if (band.band_name === name) {
        console.log("it's a match!");
        this.props.dispatch(addVote(band.objectId, band.votes));
      } else {
        console.log("addNewBand just ran");
        this.props.dispatch(addNewBand(name, url));
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm using react, javascript, and can use lodash. Any recommendations? Thanks!

edit: trying this too but not working

```
 handleVote(name, url) {
    let runOnce = true;
    this.props.bandsVoted.forEach(band => {
      if (band.band_name === name && runOnce) {
        console.log("it's a match!");
        this.props.dispatch(addVote(band.objectId, band.votes));
        runOnce = false;
      } else if (band.band_name !== name && runOnce) {
        console.log("addNewBand just ran");
        this.props.dispatch(addNewBand(name, url));
        runOnce = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to add a boolean variable which will point if the function was already called

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's wrong to use map when all you want is loop. Then just store some flag. This should work for you:

```
handleVote(name, url) {
  let matched = false

  this.props.bandsVoted.forEach(band => {
    if (band.band_name === name) {
      console.log("it's a match!");
      matched = true
      this.props.dispatch(addVote(band.objectId, band.votes));
    }
  });

  if (!matched) {
    this.props.dispatch(addNewBand(name, url));
  }
}
```

Comment: Will `this` be available inside the foreach callback?

Comment: so it works and it doesn't work. `if (band.band_name === name)` is only true if the first `band_name` matches. If it doesn't match immediately, it goes to the second condition, even if there is a match.

Comment: @bikedres `if (band.band_name === name)` will be true if `band. band_name` is equal to `name`. Not sure what you mean *"If it doesn't match immediately, it goes to the second condition, even if there is a match."*. It will go into second condition only once after the first non-match.

Comment: @dfsq I'd like it to go to the second condition if there's absolutely no match.  So far with that code it runs both `addVote` and `addNewBand`. The boolean helps though so I'm trying a few different things like...(updated my post with code I'm trying)

Comment: @bikedres So you want to `addNewBand` only if there are no matches at all? And for all matches `addVote`? Then check updated answer. You need to move `addNewBand` outside of the loop.